# image shift operation

Tags: matlab

In a MATLAB code, I have got an image called `myImage`. What is the image `Output` equal to?
The image `myImage` as a `double` 2dim matrix.

```
 Output = [ myimage(:,1) myimage(:,1:size(myimage,2)-1) ];
```

I only understand that the first column of the image `Output` "`image(:,1)`" is the first column of the image `myImage`. But what is the second? Actually, what is the `myimage(: , 1: anumber);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the original image with the last column removed and the first column duplicated.

Note that

- `myimage(:, 1:anumber)` means columns `1`,...,`anumber` of `myimage`. See [Matlab colon operator](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).
- `size(myimage,2)` is the number of columns of `myimage`. See [`size` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/size.html).

An example shows the result:

```
>> myimage = magic(4)
myimage =
    16     2     3    13
     5    11    10     8
     9     7     6    12
     4    14    15     1
>> Output = [ myimage(:,1) myimage(:,1:size(myimage,2)-1) ]
Output =
    16    16     2     3
     5     5    11    10
     9     9     7     6
     4     4    14    15
```

Comment: @user3213352 Then please mark the answer as accepted. And consider doing the same for all other questions you have asked, if you got a satisfactory answer. For that you use the big tick mark to the left of the answer. I assume that you are new and you may not know how Stack Overflow works. It's important to accept/vote answers so that answerers get the reputation points

Comment: Ok, I was just waiting some minutes to pass.

Comment: @user3213352 My apologies then :-) Since you are rather knew I assumed you might need some explanation on that