# Symbol ":" for matlab equation

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am surely new in this sector of dsp as well as matlab sector, but I would like to calculate the action below, for a matlab project.

```
 matrix = [ array(:,2:size(array,2)) array(:,size(array,2));
```

Could someone tell me what does this do? I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22021156/image-shift-in-matlab) one:

but for the action above I can not find want really does the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

- `size(array,2)`    % gives size of 2nd dimension of `array` (say `cols`)
- `array(:, 2:cols)` % all elements in each rows starting with column 2
- `array(:,cols)`    % all elements in each rows of last column
- `[ array(:,2:cols) array(:,cols) ]` % finally concatenates both matrices

Thus in `matrix` the first column is removed and last column is repeated twice

Answer (score 0):

Read as -> 
matrix = an array of 2 elements.

First element is array(:,2:size(array,2)) ie. all rows of "array" from column no. 2 to column no. size(array,2)
Now size(array,2) means total no. Of columns in "array".

Similarly for 2nd element.

Comment: Btw your brackets are not balanced.